# Convert an image to a 2D array of coordinates in Python for two point correlation

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, fft, correlation

I need to perform two-point correlation function from [astroML Python module](http://www.astroml.org/user_guide/correlation_functions.html), my data is originally a jpg image, black and white, and I convert it to binary image using [OpenCV image thresholding](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html)(not sure that I did it right). The question is how now I convert the 2D binary matrix or ones and zeros to a list of the coordinates of only the ones. The basic code line is this one:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from astroML.correlation import two_point
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im_normal = cv2.imread('example.jpg')
im_gray = cv2.imread('example.jpg', cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
(thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

Do I have to loop over all of the cells of the matrix, and pull the coordinates or is there an easy numpy way to do it?

The image on which I would like to perform the analysis   -
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, just like most things I've thought to accomplish by looping over the array: numpy has a built-in solution.

```
[numpy.nonzero][1]

numpy.nonzero(a)
Return the indices of the elements that are non-zero.

    Returns a tuple of arrays, one for each dimension of a, containing the indices of the non-zero elements in that dimension. The corresponding non-zero values can be obtained with:

    `a[nonzero(a)]`

    To group the indices by element, rather than dimension, use:

    `transpose(nonzero(a))`

    The result of this is always a 2-D array, with a row for each non-zero element.
```

Code example:

```
>>> x = np.eye(3)
>>> x
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
>>> np.nonzero(x)
(array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2]))
```